# Books and References on Geometry of Submanifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, riemannian-geometry, lagrangian-submanifolds

In this semester I want to study Geometry of Submanifolds. I know Chen Bang Yen's book: Geometry of submanifolds, but it is too hard to read since its strange print. Can people recommend textbooks and/or other references to me? If there are some online videos for the lecture, it would be more friendly to me.

Comment: Perhaps in some parts of differential geometry "Geometry of submanifold" is meaningful, but I have no idea what it is you are interested in studying.  Could you perhaps mention some characteristic theorems, or types of theorems you are interested in?

Comment: Such as Takahashi theorem. The classification theorem of total/Pseudoumbilical umbilical  theorem and the minimal submanifold on space forms, hypersurface in detail and so on.

Comment: Dajczer "Submanifolds and Isometric Immersions"

Comment: There is a new 2019 printing (with nice typesetting) of  Geometry of submanifolds by Chen Bang Yen on Dover: https://www.amazon.com/Geometry-Submanifolds-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/0486832783/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=Geometry+of+submanifolds+by+Chen+Bang+Yen&qid=1619410163&s=books&sr=1-1

Comment: The book "Critical point theory and submanifold geometry" by Richard Palais and Chuu-lian Terng is a great source. It may not contain the precise topics you're looking for, but it is excellent for the topics it covers.

Comment: @FZaldivar Do you have the eTextbook? It is too expensive in RMB not in dollar. If you have, could you send me in my email 1278603466@qq.com?